# compute vertices of a polytope with pycddlib

Tags: python, vertices

I have a code that compute de number of vertices of a polytope and the coordinates of each vertex. But I have an error for the coordinates that I didn't manage to solve.

`Error in np.array(poly.get_generators())[:, :-1] :  too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed`
Here is the code :

```
import numpy as np
import cdd as pcdd 

A = np.array([
              [-1,0,0],
              [0,-1,0],
              [1,1,0]])

b = np.array([
   [-1], 
   [-1],  
   [1]])


M = np.hstack( (b, -A) ) 


mat = pcdd.Matrix(M, linear=False, number_type="fraction")
mat.rep_type = pcdd.RepType.INEQUALITY

poly = pcdd.Polyhedron(mat)

ext = poly.get_generators() 
print(ext)


vertices = np.array(poly.get_generators())[:, :-1]
print("Vertices:")
for vertex in vertices:
   print(vertex)
```